# Simplifying some momentum and gamma matrices algebra in invariant amplitude calculation

Tags: dirac-matrices, scattering-cross-section, elementary-particles

I'm calculating some `$B_0 \rightarrow K^* \nu_R \nu_L$ decay and right now I'm stuck at invariant amplitude $\mathcal{M}$, which leads from the tensor part of Lagrangian. I'm having trouble calculating this part of it:

$$\left(P^\mu (P-k)^\nu - P^\nu (P-k)^\mu\right)\left((\bar{u}(p_1) \sigma_{\mu\nu} P_R v(p_2)\right).$$
For moments the relation applies $q^\mu = P^\mu - k^\mu = p_1^\mu + p_2^\mu$, where $P^\mu$ is $B_0$ momentum, $k^\mu$ is $K^*$ momentum, $p_1$ and $p_2$ are moments of neutrinos. Also, the tensor $\sigma_{\mu \nu}$ is $\sigma_{\mu \nu} = \frac{i}{2}[\gamma_\mu, \gamma_\nu]$.

Is it possible to get this part of the amplitude in the form with slashed notation? Or how to calculate the square of this invariant amplitude? I'm a little confused.

I hope that the question is clear.

Comment: One of your indices isn't right, otherwise I'm not sure what you want to calculate here. Until you've contracted it with the complex conjugate of the matrix elements you won't be able to get rid of these gamma matrices. In fact it is currently in a form making it much easier to do the dirac algebra simplification when you square the matrix element as previously stated

Comment: Okay, I'll square the matrix element first and then try to calculate. Thanks!